# Can AVCaptureSession use custom resolution

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm using `AVCaptureSession` to capture and record a video.

I need to record the video at a 4:3 ratio, and with a good resolution.

Is there a way to specify a custom resolution when capturing using `AVCaptureSession`?

I tried using the native presets but the problem is that I need to capture at a 4:3 ratio, and almost all of the presets are 16:9. and the ones that are 4:3 has very low resolution.

I can't fide any other way to change the preset to a custom one, what if I need to capture a 4:3 video with better resolution? Any ideas?

Comment: can u provide more info ? what preset options did u try?

Comment: did u try AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480?

Comment: @Mr.T i need a better resolution

Comment: @Eyal, if question is actual? I know how to do this with GPUImage , can answer if u want https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Answer (score 9):

`AVCaptureSession` presets cover only a small subset of the capabilities of a device camera (the ones most apps want quick, easy access to). For more fine-grained control — such as to select a capture resolution not provided by a session preset — you need to use capture formats instead.

Look at the capture device's [`formats`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/formats) property, an array of [`AVCaptureDeviceFormat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDeviceFormat_Class/index.html) objects. Enumerate through that array until you find one whose dimensions are what you want. To get the dimensions, look at the format's underlying `CMFormatDescription`:

```
let fdesc = format.formatDescription
let dims = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(fdesc)
NSLog("%d x %d", dims.width, dims.height)
```

Once you've found the format you want, lock the device for configuration and set its [`activeFormat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/activeFormat):

```
if try device.lockForConfiguration() {
    device.activeFormat = myChosenFormat
    // set up other things like activeVideoMinFrameDuration if you want
    device.unlockForConfiguration()
}
```

You can find out more about configuring a capture session via `AVCaptureDeviceFormat` in Apple's [programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2) and [the WWDC2013 session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013-610/) that introduced device formats back in iOS 7.0. (Most of what you'll find about this topic is aimed at slow-motion video, taking high-res stills during video, and other things that you can't do with session presets, but those aren't the only things you can do with capture formats.)

Comment: hi thanks for yr answer, when printing the dims it seams that there are no new dimensions, but a lot of duplicates. and i didnt find a way to create a new format (not sure its possible)

Answer (score 1):

Just record at the given aspect ratio and use an `AVMutableComposition` to crop the output video to the required aspect ratio: If you adjust the preview layer to mask to 4:3 this will appear seamless to the user.

Comment: That is going to add a lot of unnecessary overhead, especially when doing image processing.

Comment: @ChewieTheChorkie I don't understand: if you aren't getting 4:3 from hardware then yes, it is very necessary to do the conversion yourself. If you are doing image processing you a) don't want a video feed and b) will find your bottleneck further in your pipeline anyway